# configurar margens de impressão html2pdf

Tags: php, pdf

Estou utilizando o html2pdf, mas não estou conseguindo aumentar a margem de impressão. No meu html coloco `<table align="center" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0` para que a fique tudo centralizado. O maximo de tamanho que eu consigo colocar para a tabela é 670 ficando dessa forma:

```
<table align="center" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0> 
<tr>
  <td  width=335></td>
  <td  width=335></td>
</tr> 
</tr>
```

Quando eu coloco valores superiores a 670 fica descentralizado. Haveria alguma configuração no htm2PDF que poderia ser modificada para melhorar isso?
Nos exemplos que busquei [html2pdf](https://github.com/thiagosilr/Convertendo-HTML-para-PDF-Html2Pdf/blob/master/exemploQuebraDePagina.php) ele diz para modificar o `$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','pt', array(0, 0, 0, 0));` Fiz alterações, mas não surtiram efeito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido, para configurar  o html2pdf para gerar o pdf do html, utilizamos as tags:

```
<page backtop="10mm" backbottom="2mm" backleft="1mm" backright="1mm">
</page>
```

a configuração pode ser feita em

> backtop="10mm" backbottom="2mm" backleft="1mm" backright="1mm"

assim dessa forma pode-se configurar a margem de impressão do documento